# Не обновляется интерфейс при MouseMove + Timer + создание объектов

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение *WPF*, которое при проведении мыши создает объекты круга *Ellipse*.

В таймере высота и ширина их изменяется, и при достижении нулевой отметки они удаляются. Получается своеобразный хвост.

Но как только я пытаюсь отцентрировать создание по координатам мыши, приложение перестает нормально работать и зависает.

Проблема в этих строках:

```
el.Width = 10;
el.Height = 10;
Canvas.SetTop(el, e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).Y - el.Height/2);
Canvas.SetLeft(el, e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).X - el.Width/2);
```

Опытным путем было установлено, что это происходит, если подставлять значения от 4 до 7. В остальных случаях все работает хорошо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

А заодно, может быть, будут советы по улучшению кода.

Полный листинг:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Ellipse> elList = new List<Ellipse>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
            tmr.Start();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
            el.Width = 10;
            el.Height = 10;
            Canvas.SetTop(el, e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).Y - el.Height/2);
            Canvas.SetLeft(el, e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).X - el.Width/2);
            el.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            el.Stroke = Brushes.Aquamarine;
            elList.Add(el);
            this.MainCanvas.Children.Add(el);
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Ellipse el in elList)
            {
                if (el.Width < 1)
                {
                    this.MainCanvas.Children.Remove(el);
                    continue;
                }

                el.Width--;
                el.Height--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Куда подставлять? Width? Height? Или в e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).Y / X?

Comment: Вместо el.Height/2 и el.Width/2(или так оставить, там и так получается пятерка при делении). То есть получается при центрировании объектов на мышке интерфейс не обновляется до тех пор, пока я мышку не уведу за пределы окна.

Comment: @Lacky: А чему равны величины `e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).Y - el.Height/2` и `e.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas).X - el.Width/2`? Выведите их через `Debug.WriteLine` и посмотрите.

Comment: Они равны координате мыши на холсте, элементы как бы появляются, но они не уменьшаются до тех пор, пока я не уберу мышь с холста Canvas. Похоже я догадываюсь в чем дело, DispatcherTimer не получает время выполнения в потоке. Если изменить код на следующий: DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal); то все становится нормальным кроме маленькой задержки в рисовании(видимо переключение выполнения). Хотя данный феномен все еще для меня остается загадкой.

Comment: 100 миллисикунд это довольно тормозно для графики, вообще 25 милисекунд как минимум должно быть, но здесь уже нужны мультимедиа таймеры, двойная буферизация и так далее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что сообщения от таймера приходят лишь тогда, когда диспетчер не занят. Диспетчер обрабатывает сначала сообщения высокого приоритета, и лишь потом низкого, и если всё время приходят высокоприоритетные сообщения, то низкоприоритетные ждут. В вашем коде получается так, что сообщения от мыши приходят всё время, пока мышь находится над окном программы. Поэтому диспетчер занят их обработкой (и в частности вызовом `OnMouseMove`).

Поэтому имеет смысл дать таймеру более высокий приоритет:

```
DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

---

Мелочи по вашему коду:

1. Обычно в WPF не перегружают виртуальные методы, а подписываются на сообщения:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
       tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
       tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
       tmr.Start();
       InitializeComponent();
       MainCanvas.MouseMove += MainCanvas_MouseMove;
   }

   void MainCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      ...
   ```
2. В обработчике таймера вы не удаляете ненужные эллипсы из списка, в результате в списке остаётся куча ненужных эллипсов. Попробуйте так:

   ```
   void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var ellipsesToRemove = new List<Ellipse>();
       foreach (Ellipse el in elList)
       {
           if (el.Width < 1)
           {
               this.MainCanvas.Children.Remove(el);
               ellipsesToRemove.Add(el);
               continue;
           }

           el.Width--;
           el.Height--;
       }

       foreach (var el in ellipsesToRemove)
           elList.Remove(el);
   }
   ```

---

**Обновление:**

Я немного улучшил производительность, разделив наблюдение за мышью и обновление UI:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Ellipse> elList = new List<Ellipse>();
    TimeSpan reduceInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(25);
    Queue<Point> points = new Queue<Point>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Send);
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        tmr.Interval = reduceInterval;
        tmr.Start();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MainCanvas.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
    }

    void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MainCanvas.IsMouseOver)
            points.Enqueue(Mouse.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas));
    }

    int currentReduce = 0;
    void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var p in points)
            AddEllipseAt(p);
        points.Clear();
        if (currentReduce == 0)
            ReduceEllipses();
        currentReduce = (currentReduce + 1) % 10;
    }

    void AddEllipseAt(Point point)
    {
        const double elSize = 10;
        Ellipse el = new Ellipse() { Width = elSize, Height = elSize, Fill = Brushes.Blue, Stroke = Brushes.Aquamarine };
        Canvas.SetTop(el, point.Y - elSize / 2);
        Canvas.SetLeft(el, point.X - elSize / 2);
        elList.Add(el);
        this.MainCanvas.Children.Add(el);
    }

    void ReduceEllipses()
    {
        var ellipsesToRemove = new List<Ellipse>();
        foreach (Ellipse el in elList)
        {
            if (el.Width < 1)
            {
                this.MainCanvas.Children.Remove(el);
                ellipsesToRemove.Add(el);
                continue;
            }

            el.Width--;
            el.Height--;
        }

        foreach (var el in ellipsesToRemove)
            elList.Remove(el);
    }
}
```

Возможно, стоит вообще следить за мышью из отдельного потока, чтобы получать позиции за равные интервалы (но тут вступает в игру синхронизация).

Comment: ДУмаю что в таком случае все упрется в скорость рисования этих кругов, а она думаю тормозная.

Comment: @cpp_user: На моей машине (старенький Оптерон с встроенной графической картой) прекрасно летает.

Comment: Круги рисуются нормально, со скоростью все хорошо, просто для меня подобная реакция на элипс добавленный под курсор странная. Стоит добавить его чуть сбоку от мышки и все нормально, даже если на него потом навести мышкой. Ну ладно, пока приоритет выставлю, а там может и что-то получше придумаю.

Спасибо за помощь.